# Why isn't this NUnit Test Catching My Exception?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I've got a simple NUnit test:

```
[Test]
public void Invalid_ID_throws_an_exception()
{
   var zero = 0;
   var negativeNumber = -9;
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => edsp.PersonInfoById(zero));
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => edsp.PersonInfoById(negativeNumber));
}
```

and the tested method:

```
public IEnumerable<PersonInfo> PersonInfoById(int id)
{
   if (id <= 0) 
     throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(id), "ID must be greater than zero");

   yield return new PersonInfo();
}
```

... but the test fails on the first assertion because the result is `null`, rather than the expected `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`:

```
 Message: 
      Expected: <System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException>
      But was:  null
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: also, my debugger isn't stepping into my tested method `edsp.PersonInfoById` for some reason - steps right over it despite clicking "step into" when debugging.

Comment: The method you are calling and the method you show have different names. Is that just a typo?

Comment: Yep, corrected - thx @Charlie

Comment: The test passes if you force the enumeration by calling `.ToList()` on the result. E.g. `edsp.PersonInfoById(zero).ToList()`.

Comment: @srk post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test passes if you force the enumeration by calling `.ToList()` on the result.

For example:

```cs
[Test]
public void Invalid_ID_throws_an_exception()
{
   var zero = 0;
   var negativeNumber = -9;
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => edsp.PersonInfoById(zero).ToList());
   Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => edsp.PersonInfoById(negativeNumber).ToList());
}
```